# Do parenthesis in array declaration matter?

Tags: vba

Does (Excel) VBA distinguish between:

```
Dim Ghadafi as Variant
```

and

```
Dim Ghadafi() as Variant
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First syntax is **ONE** variant variable, while second represent an array of variant.

1. You can do `Ghadafi = 5.25`
2. You can do
   `Redim Preserve Ghadafi(3)

   Ghadafi(1) 5.25

   Ghadafi(2) = 6.10`

Comment: Okay, and then if you take the first and set it equal to, say, array(...), it would be equivalent to the latter, except with the latter you wouldn't have to explicitly use the word "array", am I correct?

I'm using this through the Bloomberg API and their entire system is something of a black box - not brilliant for someone learning the language :).

Comment: @MonteCarloGenerator: I think you could do that, yes, IMHO you can.... it's horrible, but if you're facing a black-box, well anything is allowed :)

Comment: A variant variable can contain anything including an array. Each element of an array of variant variables can also contain anything including an array: so you can build a ragged array.